# Clicks to http://schema.org after implementing Gmail Annotations

Tags: gmail-promo-tab

Recently added gmail promo code to our emails and are now seeing clicks to schema.org. Has anyone else encountered this?

We had to paste the code into the body of the email as the annotations didn't work when they were in the same section as styles. This now makes the code visible in the plaintext email.

```
</head>
<body class="body" style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 auto 
!important; display:block !important; min-width:100% !important; 
width:100% !important; background:#ffffff; -webkit-text-size-  
adjust:none;">
<script type="application/ld+json">
[{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Organization",
"logo": "removed for example"
},{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "DiscountOffer",
"availabilityStarts": "2019-06-23T06:00:00-04:00"
},{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "PromotionCard"
}]
</script>
```

Would like to understand if these users are actually being directed to schema.org and if there's any way around it.

Answer (score 1):

The user is not being redirected to schema.org at any point, this language is just so that Gmail understands what is going to be displayed in the enriched preview when your email populates in the highlighted bundle on the top of the promotions tab.

Please let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your ESP is converting those URLs into tracked hyperlinks, and then auto clickers are clicking the links - resulting in the data you are seeing. As your ESP is converting those into tracked hyperlinks, the Annotations will not be correctly formatted for Gmail.